# Are there uncountable antichains in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

As the title states, I am unsure of how to construct an uncountable antichain in the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

> Recall that an **antichain** is a set $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ where each element of $\mathcal{A}$ is not a subset of another element of $\mathcal{A}$.

It seems that everything I attempt requires me to assign a property to the "$n$-th set" but that already makes it countable...

Comment: From what i recall an antichain means their pairwise intersection is $\emptyset$.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri In Abbott's "Understanding Analysis" the definition I give is used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enumerate the (countably many) vertices of the infinite rooted binary tree by $\mathbb{N}$. Then each infinite path of this tree will induce an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Moreover, two such subsets are not comparable with respect to inclusion (and indeed, the intersection of two such subsets will be finite since two distinct infinite paths in this tree have only finitely many common edges.) Now try to count how many infinite paths there are in the infinite rooted binary tree.

Comment: To formalize the fact that the number of paths are uncountable, can I make an argument that choosing to "move" left or right is associated with $0$ or $1$ and we have an infinite binary sequence $\rightarrow$ The set of all infinite binary sequences is uncountable.

Comment: Yes, the set of infinite paths in this tree are in one-to-one correspondence with the set of infinite binary sequences, via the function you mentioned. By Cantor's diagonalization argument, we know that the latter set is uncountable.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Consider the binary sequence $\{1\overline{0}\}$ and $\{11\overline{0}\}$, which is basically describing $\{1\}\subset\{1,2\}$. In this case, both are infinite paths and the former is a subset of the latter.

Comment: @zony_miu: At the beginning, you are enumerating the vertices by $\mathbb{N}$, so when I say "consider a subset given by a path", I mean the set of elements of $\mathbb{N}$ which correspond to *vertices on this path*, not the subset corresponding to the path itself as an element of $2^{\mathbb{N}} \cong \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: I am getting the hang of the latter part. But I still have trouble for the former part, specifically, "the set of elements of $\mathbb{N}$ which correspond to vertices on this path". Is it possible to give an example?

Comment: @zony_miu: Suppose that I enumerated the vertices of the full binary tree as follows: The root is $0$, the vertices on the first level are $1$ and $2$ from left to right, the vertices on the second level are $3$,$4$,$5$ and $6$ from left to right etc. Then the leftmost path corresponds to the infinite subset $\{0,1,3,7,...\}$. The rightmost path corresponds to $\{0,2,6,14,...\}$. The path where you go left-right-left-right-... corresponds to $\{0,1,4,9,...\}$.

Comment: Thanks so much! This example is like an epiphany. Is it possible for you to put the example in the reply? I bet it would be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 8):

It is enough to show there exists an uncountable antichain $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{Q})$.

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A} = \{\ [\alpha-1, \alpha] \cap \mathbf{Q} \mid \alpha \in \mathbf{R} \ \}
\end{align*}

satisifies such a condition.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S\subset\mathbb{N}$.
Let $$R_S=\{p_s^t:s\in S,t\notin S\}$$, where $p_s$ is the $s^{th}$ prime number.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I thought I'd post my solution too since the $1-1$ correspondence felt more intuitive to me than the other solutions on this page.

Construct the antichain:

$$\mathcal{A} = \{\alpha : \alpha \text{ for each unique } \alpha = \{a : \text{ Either } a = 2n \text{ or } a = 2n - 1 \text{ for each } n \in \mathbb{N}\} \}$$

For the $1-1$ correspondence use the function:

$$f(\alpha) = \{n : n = \frac{a}{2} \text{ for } a \in \alpha \text{ if } a \text{ is even }\}$$

which gives you $1-1$ and onto function $f: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow P(\mathbb{N})$

The intuition is at each pair of even-odd numbers in an element in the antichain, we make a choice whether to include the even or odd number. This is equivalent to making a choice of whether to include an element in $\mathbb{N}$ or not when constructing a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.