# Proving that Antichain of Power Set of Natural Numbers Is Uncountable

Tags: analysis

Problem: Define antichain, $\Gamma$, to be a subset of the power set of natural number such that no subset in $\Gamma$ is a subset of any other element in $\Gamma$. Prove that power set of N (P(N)) contains $\Gamma$ (i.e. antichain) that is uncountable.

My attempt at the proof: 
Let $\alpha_i$ be in $\Gamma$. Then it contains some elements of natural numbers. Then we can express each $\alpha_i$ as a sequence of zeros and ones such that we sequentially take numbers in N and put zero if $\alpha_i$ does not contain that number and one if $\alpha_i$ contains that number. 
E.g. (0,1,1,1,...) would correspond to a set containing 2,3, 4.

Now we shall note that, in general, we can create an antichain for N that is infinite (e.g. just take the elements of N itself: {{1},{2},{3},...}, this would be a subset of P(N) and no two elements would be subsets of each other).

Now let $\Gamma$ be an antichain that is infinite and has maximum cardinality among all antichains. Suppose it is countable. We are going to use Cantor's Theorem to prove that it is not.

Then let 1 correspond to $\alpha_1$={$a_{11}$,$a_{12}$,$a_{13}$,...} where $a_{1i} \in$ {0,1}.
Similarly let $i \in N$ correspond to $\alpha_i$={$a_{i1}$,$a_{i2}$,...}.

Now let set $\alpha_0$ be defined such that $a_{0i}$ $\in$ $\alpha_o$ is $a_{oi}$ = 0 for $i^{th}$ 1 (one) in subset $\alpha_i$ and $a_{oi}$ = 1 otherwise (i.e. we take a sequence of 1's and put 0's in place of $i_{th}$ 1 (one) in subset $\alpha_i$). Then $\alpha_0$ is still in $\Gamma$ (it is not a subset of any other set, any other set is not subset of $\alpha_i$) but does not correspond to any natural number. Hence, $\Gamma$ is uncountable.

Comment: Certainly it does not *have* to be uncountable; is $\Gamma$ presumed to be maximal in some sense?

Comment: I am trying to prove that it is uncountable. I am also trying to avoid any theory that is beyond Analysis I course scope. $\Gamma$ is indeed presumed to be maximal of all antichains.

Comment: $\Gamma=\emptyset$ works, as does $\Gamma=\{\emptyset\}$.  The second is maximal, so some improvement is needed in the problem statement.  $\Gamma$ is a set of sets of naturals, so $\alpha_i$ is too, so it does not contain natural numbers.  I think you want $\alpha_i$ to be an element of $\Gamma$

Comment: I am paraphrasing my textbook in the wording of the question.

Comment: Here is the exact question: “Given a set B, a subset A of P (B) is called an antichain if no element of A is a subset of any other element of A. Does P (N) contain an uncountable antichain?”

Comment: To start with, you have to tell us what set you are using for your $\Gamma.$ After that, you have to prove that $\Gamma$ is an antichain, and that $\Gamma$ is uncountable. You missed out the first step: you haven't defined your $\Gamma.$ Without knowing what $\Gamma$ is, there is no way to make sense of the rest.

Comment: For example, you could start by saying: Let "$\Gamma$ be the set of all sets $X\subseteq\mathbb N$ such that, for each $n\in\mathbb N,$ $X$ contains exactly one element from the pair $\{2n-1,2n\}.$" Then you could go on to show that that set $\Gamma$ is uncountable and that it is an antichain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there uncountable antichains in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813817/are-there-uncountable-antichains-in-mathcalp-mathbbn)