Countability of Antichain
Given a set $B$, a subset $A$ of $P(B)$ is called an anti chain if no element of $A$ is a subset of any other element of $A$. Does $P(N)$ contain an uncountable anti chain? It feels impossible to me but I am not sure how to verify it. How can we prove this?

Another duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2813817/7062
